# Start Uvicorn with fastapi having main.py and app.py

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, fastapiusers

I was making an authentication backend with Fastapi following the user's guide and don't know how to start a server now.

Files and folders of the project structure are the following:

```
<project_name>/
    main.py
    app/
        app.py
```

The content of the `main.py` script:

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app.app:app", host="0.0.0.0", log_level="info")
```

The content of the `app/app.py` script:

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI

from app.db import User, create_db_and_tables
from app.schemas import UserCreate, UserRead, UserUpdate
from app.users import auth_backend, current_active_user, fastapi_users

app = FastAPI()

# Rest of the code...
```

And when I'm trying to start a server with the command from my `<project_name>/` folder:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

It gives me this error message:

> ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Attribute "app" not found in module "main".

How to start the server in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running `uvicorn app.app:app` from `<project_name>/`
(don't think your `main.py` is necessary)

Answer (score 2):

You can make sub-applications and then register them in your main.py (main application) like this:

```py
# app/app.py

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

```py
# main.py

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

from app.app import app

mainApp = FastAPI()
mainApp.mount("/app", app)  # your app routes will now be /app/{your-route-here}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(mainApp, host="0.0.0.0", log_level="info")
```

Now run your main application like this:

`uvicorn main:mainApp --reload`

Keep in mind that above example mounts your sub-application at `/app`, you your hello world route becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/`. You can do `mainApp.mount("/", app)` to mount your sub-application at root and then your hello world route becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

Read more about Sub Applications here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/

Answer (score 1):

You should run `uvicorn app:app --reload` from `<project_name>/app/`

Comment: It throws
Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".

Comment: sorry try  `uvicorn app:app --reload`

Answer (score 1):

when running the Uvicorn server, execute it from the directory containing the main.py file